# How to install some CAA code to another CATIA installation?

Tags: c++, catia, caa

I developed a new workbench in CATIA, using CAA APIs (CAA-CATIA V5 CXR27 installed + RADE matching this version).
Everything works fine on my end, now I want another user with a regular CATIA licence to be able to use my CAA dev. I have no idea if he needs a specific licence to be able to install it, or simply if he needs to modify and environment variable.

We already tried to merge my win_b64 folder with the win_b64 folder of CATIA (nop), modify the environment variable "XS_STARTCATIA_PATH" to concatenate my win_b64 folder (nop).

Is there something I need to do first, like some kind of a specific build to be able to use it with a classic CATIA licence, or anything else with the environment variables ?

Thanks in advance.